# Swift 2 - Open Split View Controller

Tags: swift, controller, segue, swift2, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` in my iOS app, but my initial view controller is a normal `UIViewController`.

I want to open the `UISplitViewController` when a button is clicked on the `UIViewController`:

```
@IBAction func openSplitViewController(sender: AnyObject) {
    let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()

    let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
    let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as! MenuTableViewController

    let rightNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as! UINavigationController
    let detailViewController = rightNavController.topViewController as! DetailViewController

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [masterViewController,detailViewController];

    self.presentViewController(splitViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But when I click the button, I get:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How should I be opening the `UISplitViewController` from the `UIViewController`?

Comment: nobody any idea´s ??

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with a `UISplitViewController`, the error you get is because one or more of your arguments is `nil`.

So make sure that all of the `viewController`s you create are real and not nil.

Look for instance at this line:

```
let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
```

At this point your `splitViewController` has no `viewController`s assigned, so `leftNavController` will be nil.  You will need to create the `navController` and `viewController` before adding them to your `splitViewController`.